# SQL select first row using cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have sql join query as follows which return multiple rows which are same but column paymentlineitem is different.

```
DECLARE @fidelisInterestItems TABLE  (claim float,payment float,code varchar(50),interest money,paymentlineitem float);

INSERT INTO @fidelisInterestItems
Select 4250692,4104926,'T4535',2.04,9425737 Union All
Select 3677431,3685465,'L1820',2.63,8485100

CREATE TABLE #tmpReport(Claim int,HCPCS varchar(50),ClaimItem int,PaymentLineItem int,Interest money,Payment int)

Insert INTO #tmpReport
 Select P.Claim, ct.code, pl.claimItem, PL.PaymentLineItem,fi.Interest,P.Payment
FROM payment p with(nolock)
        JOIN paymentlineitem pl on p.payment=pl.payment 
        JOIN cpt ct on ct.cpt=pl.cpt 
        JOIN Eob e on e.eob=p.eob 
        JOIN Eobbatch eb on eb.eobbatch=e.eobbatch 
        JOIN @fidelisInterestItems fi on p.payment=fi.payment AND p.claim=fi.claim AND ct.code=fi.code 
        WHERE p.DisbursementDate IS NULL
SELECT * FROM #tmpReport
DROP TABLE #tmpReport
```

It returns result like this:

```
+---------+-------+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+
|  Claim  | HCPCS | ClaimItem | PaymentLineItem | Interest | Payment |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+
| 4250692 | T4535 |   5552227 |         9425733 |     2.04 | 4104926 |
| 3677431 | L1820 |   4151237 |         8485098 |     2.63 | 3685465 |
| 3677431 | L1820 |   4151238 |         8485099 |     2.63 | 3685465 |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+
```

Where i want to use cte and get only first row at the time of inserting record. I did tried using select top 1 but the records are more.
Expected result should be only first two row where 3rd row is having two same records and second records needs to excluded.

Expected Result on inserting it should insert only these two reocrds in #tmpReport:

```
+---------+-------+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+
|  Claim  | HCPCS | ClaimItem | PaymentLineItem | Interest | Payment |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+
| 4250692 | T4535 |   5552227 |         9425733 |     2.04 | 4104926 |
| 3677431 | L1820 |   4151237 |         8485098 |     2.63 | 3685465 |
+---------+-------+-----------+-----------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: It seems likely there is some missing information here. Like, what is your desired result, besides one row, should there be some sort of order to it? Also, what you built is a temporary table, not really a Common Table Expression (CTE). They work similiarly, but are not the same thing.

Comment: When we are inserting into #tmpreport it should only insert first two rows as i want to take top 1 for payment=3685465

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @fidelisInterestItems TABLE  (claim float,payment float,code varchar(50),interest money,paymentlineitem float);

INSERT INTO @fidelisInterestItems
Select 4250692,4104926,'T4535',2.04,9425737 Union All
Select 3677431,3685465,'L1820',2.63,8485100

CREATE TABLE #tmpReport(Claim int,HCPCS varchar(50),ClaimItem int,PaymentLineItem int,Interest money,Payment int)

with cte as 
(
Select P.Claim, ct.code, pl.claimItem, PL.PaymentLineItem,fi.Interest,P.Payment, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by P.Claim, ct.code order by (select null)) as ranking 
-- Include other columns in `partition by` which have to be equal to omit the next record
FROM payment p with(nolock)
        JOIN paymentlineitem pl on p.payment=pl.payment 
        JOIN cpt ct on ct.cpt=pl.cpt 
        JOIN Eob e on e.eob=p.eob 
        JOIN Eobbatch eb on eb.eobbatch=e.eobbatch 
        JOIN @fidelisInterestItems fi on p.payment=fi.payment AND p.claim=fi.claim AND ct.code=fi.code 
        WHERE p.DisbursementDate IS NULL
)
Insert INTO #tmpReport
Select * from cte where ranking = 1 
SELECT * FROM #tmpReport
DROP TABLE #tmpReport
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, row_number() over (partition by Claim, code, claimItem, Interest, Payment order by PaymentLineItem) as seqnum
      FROM #tmpReport t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Or aggregation:

```
select Claim, code, claimItem, Interest, Payment, MIN(PaymentLineItem) as PaymentLineItem
from #tmpReport t
group by Claim, code, claimItem, Interest, Payment;
```

Comment: I would give you points for the first query. Much more concise than `WITH cte AS ( ...`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly this should work:

```
DECLARE @fidelisInterestItems TABLE  (claim float,payment float,code varchar(50),
interest money,paymentlineitem float);

INSERT INTO @fidelisInterestItems
Select 4250692,4104926,'T4535',2.04,9425737 Union All
Select 3677431,3685465,'L1820',2.63,8485100

CREATE TABLE #tmpReport(Claim int,HCPCS varchar(50),ClaimItem int,
PaymentLineItem int,Interest money,Payment int)

INSERT INTO #tmpReport
SELECT P.Claim, ct.code, pl.claimItem, PL.PaymentLineItem,fi.Interest,P.Payment
FROM payment p with(nolock)
        JOIN paymentlineitem pl on p.payment = pl.payment 
        JOIN cpt ct on ct.cpt = pl.cpt 
        JOIN Eob e on e.eob = p.eob 
        JOIN Eobbatch eb on eb.eobbatch = e.eobbatch 
        JOIN @fidelisInterestItems fi on p.payment = fi.payment 
            AND p.claim = fi.claim AND ct.code = fi.code 
        WHERE p.DisbursementDate IS NULL
            AND P.payment = 3685465

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #tmpReport

DROP TABLE #tmpReport
```

However, I still don't get what your criteria is for the first row, such as `ORDER BY pl.ClaimItem` or something. But, perhaps it doesn't matter?

Comment: Updated question, I want result like this.

Comment: There's too much guess work here, but it looks like you need a `GROUP BY P.payment` here. But, without knowing about what you're trying to do, I cannot really guide you any further. If (for instance) you're looking for the MIN of each column, then that could accomplish your goal. Assuming that was correct, just change the `#tempReport` query to `SELECT MIN(Claim) AS Claim, MIN(code) AS HCPCS, MIN(claimItem) AS claimItem, MIN(PaymentLineItem) AS PaymentLineItem, MIN(Interest) AS Interest, Payment FROM #tmpReport GROUP BY Payment`. Otherwise, you will need to figure out how you want to group it.